# Implementing goto in an ast

Tags: python, interpreter, goto, abstract-syntax-tree, ply

Background:
As a short project over winter break, I'm trying to implement a programming language called Axe (designed for graphing calculators) using Python and PLY.  A brief note: the language allows only global variables and makes heavy use of pointers.

**I'm trying to implement goto in this language, but have no idea how to do it.**

My general method is to first use PLY to parse the code into an ast, then walk through it executing as I go.

For example, the statement

```
If 3
    Disp 4
    Disp 6
End
```

...would turn into...

```
['PROGRAM', 
  ['BLOCK', 
    ['IF', 
      ['CONDITION', 3], 
      ['BLOCK', 
        ['DISP', 4], 
        ['DISP', 6]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

...which I would execute recursively (I added indents for readability).

Because the ast is a tree, I'm not sure how to jump between different nodes.  I've considered perhaps converting the tree to a flat-ish array `['IF', ['CONDITION', 3], ['DISP', 4], ['DISP', 6]]` so that I can use the indices of the flat-ish array to go to specific lines in the code, but this seems to lack a certain elegance and almost feels like a step backwards (although I could be wrong).

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780195/goto-statement-in-antlr), but was unable to understand how it worked.

Any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: "Jump"?  What do you think you mean by "Jump"?  Why would you "jump" between nodes?  Please provide a specific example where you would "jump" to an arbitrary node.  It's difficult to find a sensible need for a jump in a tree-based language.

Comment: The language I'm choosing to implement has goto statements in it.  I wanted to match the spec, which is why I need goto.  I made this tree-based because it seemed like a sensible thing to do at the time.  I'm guessing that was a mistake: what other forms of languages are there?

Comment: AXE really *requires* a GOTO?  Seems odd.  There an infinite number of "forms" of languages: procedural, functional, etc., etc.  Among procedural languages, Python and Java (among others) have no GOTO.  It's a pretty rare thing.

Comment: AST is good at compiling, not at evaluation. Except `goto` there are other problem - loops. How you want to implement loops without some sort of program counter?

Comment: It's a low level language.  Also, I implemented loops earlier by using a 'while' loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"execute recursively" doesn't fit well with `goto`. For `goto` to work, you need a PC, a "program counter" and each statement in your program must have a distinct address. As it is executed, the address of each statement is assigned to the PC. When `goto` is encountered, the target address of the goto (it's argument) is put into the PC and the execution resumes from there.

This is almost impossible to achieve with a stack-based, recursive approach. You have two options:

- Flatten your AST into a sequence where you can assign a distinct address to each statement
- Add a "skip" mode to your interpreter. When `goto` is encountered, throw a `GotoException` which breaks out of all of the stack frames and goes back to the root. Process statements (skip them without executing) until you reach the target address.

I think you can imagine that this implementation of `goto` isn't very performant and probably brittle to implement.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions!  I think I'm going to go with flattening the tree.

Answer (score 3):

> I've considered perhaps converting the tree to a flat-ish array ... but this seems to lack a certain elegance and almost feels like a step backwards (although I could be wrong).

You are wrong.  Machine code is always flat.  Languages like C are flattened to create machine code.

A calculator (like other simple machines) is flat.

However.  Flattening out your AXE syntax tree is not completely *necessary*.

You simply need to apply the programming source labels to each node in your tree.

Then a "GOTO" simply searches the tree for that label and resumes execution at that label.

Comment: Ah, good point about the machine code.  I guess I was wrong about that then :)

Comment: Because machine code is flat, we don't use it often for programming nowadays.  We prefer structured languages and use tools to flatten a nice, structured language into the flat world of machine execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also flatten the AST to a directed graph (the control-flow graph). An example of how this can be done to produce a [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) graph that can be traversed by the interpreter can be found [in the Python package `promela`](https://github.com/johnyf/promela/blob/30f9d06af11163befd1b19d812d4262e4f87138d/promela/ast.py#L414). Note that you'll have to write some AST classes for that purpose.